# How to set the visibilty of button in a custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, button, android-listview, visibility

I have a custom `ListView` with a `button`, so when I click on a `button` it should disappear and it is disappearing but when I scroll down and come back the `button` is again appearing and a different `button` is getting disappeared. How can i make the specific `button` to disappear on clicking.... I am using this code

```
holder.checkbox = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Have you got your solution? If you got it from any on of the answer then accept it otherwise post your answer. If you accept an answer it will help others and your reputation will also increase.

Comment: i would defenitely but i dint get a good solution may be all the answers works but i am not able to figure out which to tick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ListView when an item goes out of screen,  for efficiency ListView destroys the item and when scrolling back to that item it recreates it by calling getView() method of adapter so you have to keep an array having a boolean for the status of the button which is by default will be true as for visible and in getView() you just put a check by getting the boolean value of status from the boolean array that if true then item is visible else item is invisible. So when you disappear an item you have to set status of item also false.
I assume this is the code in your getView() and you have already defined your array of boolean with same length as items of ListView and value of true with name "yourButtonStatusBooleanArray" then following modifications will work for you.

```
holder.checkbox = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

if(!yourButtonStatusBooleanArray[position])
{
 holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
yourButtonStatusBooleanArray[position]=false;
```

Comment: you mean "Boolean yourButtonStatusBooleanArray = true" ??

Comment: boolean[] yourButtonStatusBooleanArray = new boolean[yourListViewItems.size()];  Arrays.fill(yourButtonStatusBooleanArray, true);

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`after the button declaration

Comment: it is kinda working but when i scroll down and come back the button i clicked on is appearing again...

Comment: It's because of ListView reusing resources. Try looking at this answer they gave me for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15900881/1006156

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because of view recycling. What you need to do is maintain an array of say booleans and every time a button is clicked toggle the corresponding boolean. Then in your getview check the corresponding boolean array position and set the state of the button.

for more detail reffer this link

[check box in listview not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248940/check-box-in-listview-not-working-properly)

above example is for check box edit your code.

Comment: i am not having a checkbox, im having a button, so will that still work??

Comment: yup. u ll have to just check the state of clicked button. it does'nt matter rather it is check box or button

Comment: just add the lines in your code which is marked as "new" in that link

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the view of the row is reused and therefore after scrolling the row view might be displaying the button with the state of a different row. You could solve this problem by explicitly setting the visibility of your button on initialization of the view. So you would have to remember the state of the row somewhere e.g. in your data object or in an array that keeps track of the already selected items.

```
holder.checkbox.setVisibility(dataObject.getVisibilityState());
```

EDIT Answer to comment, shown here to have code blocks

you have to implement the Method yourself, the code was just an example how a custom method could be used. So you could do something like this in you item Class:

```
 public class Item {
 private int visibility;
 ... other attributes of your item

 public int getVisibilityState(){
  return visibility;
 }

 public void setVisible(){
  visibility = View.VISIBLE;
 }

 public void setInvisible(){
  visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
 }
 }
```

Comment: i am getting an error "The method getVisibilityState() is undefined for the type List<Item>"

Comment: you have to implement the Method yourself, the code was just an example how a custom method could be used. So you could do something like this in you item Class:
    
     `public class Item {
     private int visibility;
     ... other attributes of your item

     public int getVisibilityState(){
      return visibility;
     }

     public void setVisible(){
      visibility = View.VISIBLE;
     }

     public void setInvisible(){
      visibility = View.INVISIBLE;
     }
     }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement this method in your ListAdapter which is called every time your View of the row goes from off-screen to on-screen due to the user scrolling the list.  The View passed to your getView method may actually be used to display data for a totally different row.  This is because the objects are recycled - if you have data for 1,000 rows but only 8 views fit onscreen, the system creates 8 View objects for your rows, not 1,000.

If your class implements ListAdapter you can override the getView method as follows:

```
public class MyClass implements ListAdapter {

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View rowView = convertView;

//Create a view for this row if none exists yet
if (rowView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_ROW_LAYOUT, parent, false);

//make the button go away if it should not be visible
if (buttonShouldBeNotVisible(convertView)) {  //Your code should determine this
    convertView.checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    //Use View.GONE to make it take up no space
}
return convertView
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

The views are recycled in the listview. You will have to save the state of the button in some kind of data structure and set it in the adapters `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`.

```
private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mButtonMap = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

[...]

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View retVal;

    // Do all your stuff with each row



    if (!mButtonMap.containsKey(new Integer(position))) {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    button.setTag(""+position);
    return retVal;
}

//In your onClickListener
    onClick(View v) {
        [...]
        int position = Integer.parseInt((String) v.getTag());
        mButtonMap.put(position, true); 
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: there is a small error "The method Integer(int) is undefined for the type ListRowAdapter", how can i resolve this??

Comment: 04-30 09:14:44.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4214): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
04-30 09:14:44.463: E/AndroidRuntime(4214):  at com.envesage.ListRowAdapter$1.onClick(ListRowAdapter.java:341)

Comment: Strange. Well, try 'int position = (Integer) v.getTag();' instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_adapter, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkbox = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (arg0.getTag().equals("0")) {
                        arg0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        arg0.setTag("1");
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        try {

            if (holder.checkbox.getTag().equals("1")) {
                holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return vi;
    }
```